# How to emit noise around center frequency inside some bandwidth

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to emit white noise around specific center frequency inside bandwidth using AudioKit for iOS.
Core of what I did so far looks like this:

```
class Manager {

    private let noise = AKWhiteNoise(amplitude: Default.amplitude)

    private lazy var filter: AKEqualizerFilter = {
        let max = AKEqualizerFilter.gainRange.upperBound
        return AKEqualizerFilter(noise, centerFrequency: Default.centerFrequency, bandwidth: Default.bandwidth, gain: max)
    }()

    var bandwidth: Double {
        get {
            return filter.bandwidth
        }
        set {
            filter.bandwidth = newValue
        }
    }

    var centerFrequency: Double {
        get {
            return filter.centerFrequency
        }
        set {
            filter.centerFrequency = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Noise is emitted, but that's how looks [sound before playing noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW0wY.png) and that's how [after adding noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS8m5.png).

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong and how to fix sound to fit given center frequency and bandwidth?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the problem is here. What were the input parameters for the two screenshots you provide? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something in shape like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Bandwidth_2.svg). Modifying bandwidth would change width of graph and updating center frequency would move everything to left or right but I need that noise to be always around center frequency.